# Unable to create Jupyter notebook in Ubuntu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am unable to create jupyter notebook in Ubuntu. I checked others answers, they were saying to change the permission setting of '/home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter'. But, there is no '/home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter' with my installation. My Jupyter version is 5.0.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `which jupyter` to see where it's installed and then change the permission on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try command in terminal:

```
export PATH=/your-path-to-jupyter:$PATH
jupyter notebook
```